# how to separate frontend and admin feature in spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

I’m using latest spree 3.7.0. And Rails5.2 and Ruby 2.5.0.
I’d like to know how to separate frontend and admin feature.
Actually, I have another admin application. So I’d like to integrate spree admin into this.

After install rails new app, I entered below command.

```
rails g spree:install
```

Then the app automatically install whole app including frontend and admin.
But if possible, I'd like to separate into two like frontend and admin.
Give me advise, please.

Comment: have you read the documentation? https://github.com/spree/spree
maybe also look here https://guides.spreecommerce.org/developer/customization/view.html

Comment: I read the doc. Sorry, my explanation is wrong. I'd like to sprit current spree app. localhost:3000 and localhost:3001/admin.
I think service application and admin application should be apart. The last thing I want to do is to make 2 app and delete each feature.