# Installing only admin and no admin on spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I’m using latest spree 3.7.0. And Rails5.2 and Ruby 2.5.0. I’d like to know how to install without admin.
And I'd like to know how to install only **admin**.

When I install spree using below command,

```
rails g spree:install
```

service feature and **admin** feature is installed altogether.

Comment: Didn't you ask [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55197007/how-to-separate-frontend-and-admin-feature-in-spree) yesterday?

Comment: @jvillian Yeah, I thought my question didn't make sense. So I changed my question.